# Can't downgrade to matplotlib 1.2.1 using enpkg

Tags: matplotlib, enthought

I just installed Canopy Express 1.4.1 (64 bit) on a Mac running OS 10.6.8, and encountered the same problem with import of pylab that anakha272 reported in the question [Matplotlib import error ft2font](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24768145/1904584)  I tried the workaround given in the answer to that question, but the downgrade to matplotlib 1.2.1 failed with the following error message in the Canopy terminal window:

`% enpkg --no-deps matplotlib 1.2.1`

`HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND`

(followed by various additional diagonstics which I'll spare you since I believe they all descend from the 404 error).

Is `matplotlib 1.2.1` no longer available?  Does anybody known another workaround if I want to use pylab with the Canopy distribution?

Comment: It's there. Are you working behind a proxy? What do you get from `enpkg --search matplotlib` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not behind a proxy, but after trying this and a few other enpkg commands, I found that I get the same error message regardless of what enpkg command I'm using, so it has nothing to do with matplotlib. Evidently, there is some problem with the way my installation is configured which is preventing enpkg from working. I'll check it out and report back.